# Filter SharePoint Data To InfoPath Based on Username

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

Basically I have an InfoPath form which recieves some data from a SharePoint list, the problem is I would like to filter this data based on the username of the current user.

So I have an Author field in SharePoint which is a 'Person/Group' field.

So when I filter the data in InfoPath by saying

```
where Author is equal to UserName()
```

I also tried `contains`

But it still doesnt work, does anyone have any ideas on a solution?

Note that using code is not an option in this case!

Comment: How are you querying the list? Are you using Lists.asmx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this issue by using just the username in the SharePoint column as opposed to the full person/group structure, this way I can match the two username in InfoPath.